# What's the song on season 2 episode 24 when Meliodas was cooking something and Elizabeth came to meet him?

Tags: music, seven-deadly-sins

There's a song playing on *Nanatsu no Taizai: Imashime no Fukkatsu* episode 24 (last episode) at about 13:04 when Meliodas was cooking something and Elizabeth came to meet him at the Broken Boar's hut.

What is the name of the song?

Answer (score 2):

Song: Chikai
Artist: Sora Amamiya